# Exclude list of letters in a string from list of words

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, search

I am a bit in trouble in a way to select a bunch of letters in a for loop that select words in a list which do not contain these letters;

Bellow the code I am trying to use, when I assign string with just one char, it print all words in words.txt that do not contain that char, but if I assign string with more than one char it consider the whole string, even using a ( for letter in string )

```
def avoids_2():
    string = 'abc'
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for letter in string: 
        for line in fin:
            if letter not in line:
                word = line.strip()
                print(word)
```

Please, does anyone knows how to solve ?

Comment: It's not exactly clear--is `words.txt` one word per line? Please show your input, expected output and show what's failing. Thanks.

Comment: do add a sample of words.txt & a sample output you aim for that input

Comment: actually words.txt is a database of all mapped english words, but they are not on per line. However, words are separated. Sorry for not sharing it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with your code is that you are searching for only one character at a time i.e if your letter is `c` it will look for only `c` and print strings with `a` or `b` too in the internal loop. So you can change it like this

```
fin = open('words.txt')
test_string = 'abc'
for line in fin:
    flag = False
    for letter in test_string:
        if letter in line:
            flag = True
            break
    if not flag:
        print(line.strip())
```

You can also use regex here

```
import re

fin = open('words.txt')

for line in fin:
   if re.match(r'a|b|c', line):
      continue
   print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sherlcode13 it was exactly what was happening. Your solution worked properly!